# Hardware error in Reliability Monitor in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hardware-failure

I found hardware error in Reliability Monitor.

[image]

How can I find out which hardware part is suspected for hardware error?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a driver error or a hardware error.

**Drivers:**  Get your computer manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all drivers including BIOS.

**Hardware:**  Get your computer manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and check all hardware.

**Memory:**  Get memtest86.exe and make a bootable USB key. Boot with this key and test memory (two or three passes).

The answers below may also help, particularly the Answers link.

Check this technical Microsoft Article

[Bugcheck 0xd1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xd1--driver-irql-not-less-or-equal)

> The DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL bug check has a value of 0x000000D1.
> This indicates that a kernel-mode driver attempted to access pageable
> memory while the process IRQL that was too high.
>
> the problem is caused by the driver that you are developing, make
> sure that the function that was executing at the time of the bug check
> is (1) not marked as pageable or (2) does not call any other inline
> functions that could be paged out

Also this Answers Link

[Bugcheck 0x000000d1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsod-cause-of-a-bug-check-0x000000d1/bb4345b9-5206-4132-8137-4347f01e79c0?auth=1)

> Bug Check 0xD1: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> The DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL bug check has a value of 0x000000D1.
> This indicates that a kernel-mode driver attempted to access pageable
> memory at a process IRQL that was too high.
>
> Important Info If You Have Received a STOP Code
>
> If you received a blue screen error, or stop code, the computer has
> shut down abruptly to protect itself from data loss. A hardware
> device, its driver, or related software might have caused this error.
> If your copy of Windows came with your computer, call the manufacturer
> of your computer

**Follow up:** This is a Lenovo computer. Windows had to be reinstalled.  Be certain that you are using the Lenovo supplied Recovery USB (you can make one on your computer).

Comment: Thank you for replying and explaining. I am very much disappointed with manufacturer (Lenovo) procedures.
They diagnosed multiple times and every time they used Lenovo Diagnostic Tools. Even at full run test, the tool doesn’t show any hardware issue. At the end executive says, Clean Install Windows. I installed windows multiple times. However, I am facing BSOD issues very frequently.

Comment: After diagnosing minidump, it’s because of display driver which AMD Radeon. At one scenario, I updated AMD Radeon, however, BSOD issue occurred multiple times. At another scenario after Clean Windows installation, I didn’t update AMD Radeon, however BSOD issue occurs frequently.

Comment: Manufacturer is not ready to accept hardware issue. Hardly I found it at Reliability Monitor.

Comment: [Lenovo] ...  Even at full run test, the tool doesn’t show any hardware issue. At the end executive says, Clean Install Windows. I installed windows multiple times.  ...  That is strange.  I use Lenovo commercial computers myself.  Do run the Memtest.exe test. If no other hardware, memory would figure high on the list.   Can you get Lenovo to replace the machine under warranty?

Comment: Also, when reinstalling Windows on this Lenovo computer, use only the Lenovo Recovery USB (you can make one on your computer). Do not use the Microsoft ISO (drivers need to be Lenovo).  I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: As you said, use only the Lenovo Recovery USB (you can make one on your computer). Do not use the Microsoft ISO (drivers need to be Lenovo). Like you, someone said, use Lenovo Recovery.  Previously I did Clean Windows Installation 5 times but I used Microsoft ISO. During all installations, I removed all volumes created.

Comment: Please let me know, how both are different? How can I do Clean Installation using Lenovo Recovery USB?

Comment: The Microsoft ISO is generic and uses the Microsoft Catalogue for drivers. There may be other Lenovo only drivers you should be using.

Comment: I just found a link, how to create Lenovo Recovery USB. The procedure uses exiting installed Windows for creating Recovery USB. Currently Windows has BSOD issues and hardware issues. At this scenario, is it okay to create a Recovery USB from installed Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124083/discussion-between-einfomail-and-john).

Comment: Yes, you can use the Lenovo Recovery USB to reinstall Windows. You should not see hardware errors from that.

Comment: Moreover, please let me know. Clean Installation process from Microsoft ISO and Clean Installation process from Lenovo Recovery; how both installation process will be different?

Comment: Lenovo Recovery USBs do a good job of setting up Windows. I have used them and keep them on hand. All drivers will be properly installed and that can be different than the generic Microsoft install. It too installs drivers but the Lenovo USB install is normally better.

Comment: I got it. At the time of installation process from Lenovo Recovery USB, do I need to connect the Laptop with Internet? And any change in Installation steps?

Comment: At some point, yes you need Internet. I normally use Ethernet for this. Installation steps are automatic or just OK.